# Need assistance on objects in PyCaret

Tags: python, pycaret

I am learning PyCaret. It is a fantastic program. I have the following questions:

1)After running `lr = create_model('lr', fold = 5)`, I get a nice table with accuracy etc.

```
>>>print(type(lr))
<class 'sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier'>
```

How can I find the data in this class `sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier`. Is there any way to convert to a pd dataframe for export?

2)`plot_model(lr)` creates a nice AUC graph. `fig=plot_model(lr)` also creates the same nice graph. But

```
>>>print(type(fig))
<class 'NoneType'>
```

so I cannot save the figure and export it. I can add `save=True` to the code but this will save the figure as auc.png, which is OK, but I would like to save the figures with different names.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to store the score grid that is printed when you use `create_model`, you can use `pull` functionality. For example:

```
lr = create_model('lr')
lr_results = pull()
type(lr_results) # it will be a pandas DataFrame
```

Currently, there is no way to change the plot name when saving. You can use `save` param inside `plot_model` to save it but it will use the default naming of PyCaret For e.g. `AUC.png` for AUC plot.